# yii\base\InvalidParamException with message The view file does not exist

Tags: php, yii2

I'm very new to Yii framework.
I did only basic compulsory steps in setting up **advance Yii**. But it gives the following error when I try load the `index.php`(localhost:8888/new/advanced/frontend/web/index.php) in frontend as well as the `index.php` (localhost:8888/new/advanced/backend/web/index.php) in the backend.

**Things I have done from the beginning:**

1. Downloaded the advanced Yii framework & extracted it to the htdocs
2. Run the command `php init` in the terminal.
   that's all...

I tried this solution [yii2-error-the-view-file-does-not-exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34396976/yii2-error-the-view-file-does-not-exist).. but it didn't worked

---

**Error**

> ```
> An Error occurred while handling another error:
> exception 'yii\base\InvalidParamException' with message 'The view file does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SMS_Messenger/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/views/errorHandler/exception.php' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/new/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php:226
> Stack trace:
> #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/new/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/ErrorHandler.php(241): yii\base\View->renderFile('@yii/views/erro...', Array, Object(yii\web\ErrorHandler))
> #1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/new/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/ErrorHandler.php(112): yii\web\ErrorHandler->renderFile('@yii/views/erro...', Array)
> #2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/new/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/ErrorHandler.php(109): yii\web\ErrorHandler->renderException(Object(yii\base\InvalidParamException))
> #3 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(yii\base\InvalidParamException))
> #4 {main}
> Previous exception:
> exception 'yii\base\InvalidParamException' with message 'The file or directory to be published does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SMS_Messenger/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/assets' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/new/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/AssetManager.php:452
> Stack trace:
> #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/new/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/AssetBundle.php(179): yii\web\AssetManager->publish('/Applications/M...', Array)
> #1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/new/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/AssetManager.php(266): yii\web\AssetBundle->publish(Object(yii\web\AssetManager))
> #2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/new/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/AssetManager.php(237): yii\web\AssetManager->loadBundle('yii\\web\\YiiAsse...', Array, true)
> #3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/new/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/View.php(284): yii\web\AssetManager->getBundle('yii\\web\\YiiAsse...')
> #4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/new/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/View.php(289): yii\web\View->registerAssetBundle('yii\\web\\YiiAsse...', NULL)
> #5 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/new/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/AssetBundle.php(123): yii\web\View->registerAssetBundle('frontend\\assets...')
> #6 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/new/advanced/frontend/views/layouts/main.php(13): yii\web\AssetBundle::register(Object(yii\web\View))
> #7 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/new/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php(325): require('/Applications/M...')
> #8 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/new/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php(247): yii\base\View->renderPhpFile('/Applications/M...', Array)
> #9 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/new/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(392): yii\base\View->renderFile('/Applications/M...', Array, Object(frontend\controllers\SiteController))
> #10 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/new/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(378): yii\base\Controller->renderContent('<div class="sit...')
> #11 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/new/advanced/frontend/controllers/SiteController.php(75): yii\base\Controller->render('index')
> #12 [internal function]: frontend\controllers\SiteController->actionIndex()
> #13 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/new/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(55): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
> #14 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/new/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(154): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
> #15 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/new/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(454): yii\base\Controller->runAction('', Array)
> #16 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/new/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(84): yii\base\Module->runAction('', Array)
> #17 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/new/advanced/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(375): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
> #18 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/new/advanced/frontend/web/index.php(18): yii\base\Application->run()
> #19 {main}
> ```

---

**frontend sitecontroller.php**

```
<?php
namespace frontend\controllers;

use Yii;
use common\models\LoginForm;
use frontend\models\PasswordResetRequestForm;
use frontend\models\ResetPasswordForm;
use frontend\models\SignupForm;
use frontend\models\ContactForm;
use yii\base\InvalidParamException;
use yii\web\BadRequestHttpException;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
class SiteController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['logout', 'signup'],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['signup'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['?'],
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['logout'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'logout' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function actions()
{
    return [
        'error' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
        ],
        'captcha' => [
            'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
            'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
        ],
    ];
}

/**
 * Displays homepage.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionIndex()
{
    return $this->render('index');
}

//other codes
```

My environment is Mac OS 10.11 El capitain
since I'm very newbie to Yii & I haven't changed the default code its hard to figure out the problem.
Hope for any suggestion

Comment: I downloaded the archive file from yiframework.com & it also reffers to the same link that you have sent

Comment: Why do you have 2 different paths : `SMS_Messenger` and `new/advanced` ? Real path is `new/advanced`.

Comment: The preferred way to install  yii2 advanced template is by using a composer?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have vendor directory.
Run composer from command line. Probably you must first install composer. Then in root dir of advanced project run:

```
composer install
```

or

```
php composer install
```